# C# Webbrowser copy link to navigate back

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Im using a WebBrowser in my software like this:

```
browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate("www.mywebsite.com");
```

After it opens the website, you can navigate to different places. Now I want to copy the link of the last place I visited before I close the webbrowser, so I can navigate back from my c# software.

Does anyone have an idea how this could work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribed to Navigated Event, and added all the navigated address to the collection variable.

```
List<String> navigatedAddressList = new List<string>();

public MainWindow()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    browser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    browser.Navigated += Browser_Navigated;
}


 private void Browser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    navigatedAddressList.Add(e.Uri.ToString());
}
```

Add/Remove from the Collection based on the Button click and provide it to Browser when needed.